# SQL SYNTAX ERROR PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to echo how many minutes left from the specific date ( CURDATE() ).

That's how i've done it:

```
public function getTimeLeft($ip)
{
    $this->get = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'nextVote')); FROM auths WHERE voter_ip = :ip");
    $this->get->execute(array(":ip" => $ip));
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php:174 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php(174): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\index.php(644): Vote->getTimeLeft('127.0.0.1') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vote\includes\class\Vote.class.php on line 174
```

What is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: `'nextVote'` is being treated as a string because of the quotes. Did you mean ````nextVote```` with backticks `?

Comment: I get the same error after removing the strings ' '.

Comment: Remove the `;` before `FROM`. And [MySQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) expects 2 parameters, you're just providing 1.

Comment: Already done this, doesn't really work. thats how the nextVote column looks like: 2013-05-12 12:00:00

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro wondering how can I do this with 2 parameters

Comment: Just read the function documentation and you'll manage.

Comment: I did read it but kind of don't understand how would this go to what I want to make, is there a chance you could drop a little example? ^^

Comment: My intution says that you have to use NOW() instead of CURDATE() so TIMEDIFF can calculate difference between two values with the same format.

Comment: @user2363542 Read the **official** documentation, it's full of examples.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), nextVote), '%Y %m %d %h %i %s') did I do anything wrong? cause it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2363542 - what is the TIMEDIFF(CURDATE(), nextVote) returning? test by running such a query in your sql-client.

Comment: It is returning 2013-05-12 12:00:00

Comment: UPDATE auths SET nextVote = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR

Comment: How does your query look like (with values sent to your function) in its whole? Are you able to execute that query in your sql-client?

Comment: I belive you should use NOW() instead of CURDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can separate multiple SQL statements with a semi-colon `;`, but I
  wouldn't put one in the middle of your query!
- `DATE_FORMAT` takes two parameters.  The second is a [format string](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp).
- `'nextVote'` is a string literal, try nextVote or `nextVote` for a column name
- `curdate()` returns the date.  Use `now()` for the full date and time.  [See here for an example.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

So could try something like:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), nextVote), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
FROM    auths 
WHERE   voter_ip = :ip
```

Comment: This really deserves more upvotes.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Thanks but I wouldn't think so, most points were raised in the comments before I submitted my answer.

Comment: Too lazy to read them all.

Answer (score 1):

CURDATE() returns only the date without any time. Also DATE_FORMAT requires a second parameter specifying the format you want. i.e. '%m-%d-%Y %T'.

You can do this a couple of ways:

**Using TIMEDIFF**

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), `nextVote`)
FROM auths
WHERE `voter_id` = :ip
```

Returns:

```
-71:27:44
```

**If you only want minutes you can use TIMESTAMPDIFF**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `nextVote`, NOW())
FROM auths
WHERE `voter_id` = :ip
```

Returns:

```
-4288
```

**NOTE: TIMEDIFF(a, b) is a-b while TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, a, b) is b-a.**

Comment: +1 and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You might consider staying closer to the question, it doesn't mention the minutes option.

Comment: Thanks. I added the minutes option because of the "trying to echo how many minutes left" in his question.